# How to disable multi-button in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
    Protected Sub Calendar1_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Calendar1.SelectionChanged



    Dim db As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\Users\jonhny\Desktop\FinalProject\Backup\Backup\Backup\FinalProject\Database.accdb'")
    If db.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        db.Close()
    End If

    db.Open()

    Dim reservationDate As String = Calendar1.SelectedDate
    Dim reserved As String


    Dim table As String


    Dim booking As String = "SELECT BookingDate, NumberOfTable FROM CustomerReservation WHERE BookingDate='" & reservationDate & "'"
    Dim sqlcommand1 As New OleDbCommand(booking, db)

    Dim dr1 As OleDbDataReader

    dr1 = sqlcommand1.ExecuteReader


    If dr1.HasRows Then
        dr1.Read()

        reserved = dr1.Item("BookingDate")
        Table = dr1.Item("NumberOfTable")

    End If
    dr1.Close()


    If reservationDate < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) Then
        lblShowMessage.Text = "*You can't select previous date!"
        lblShowMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        lblShowDate.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate
        btnPToPayment.Visible = False

    ElseIf reservationDate < DateTime.Now.AddDays(7) Then
        lblShowMessage.Text = "*You have to reserve 7 days earlier!"
        lblShowMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        lblShowDate.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate
        btnPToPayment.Visible = False

    ElseIf reservationDate = reserved Then

        lblShowMessage.Text = "*This day not Available!"
        lblShowMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        lblShowDate.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate
        btnPToPayment.Visible = False

        Button1.Visible = True
        Button2.Visible = True
        Button3.Visible = True
        Button4.Visible = True
        Button5.Visible = True
        Button6.Visible = True
        Button7.Visible = True
        Button8.Visible = True
        Button9.Visible = True
        Button11.Visible = True
        Button12.Visible = True
        Button13.Visible = True
        Button14.Visible = True
        Button15.Visible = True
        Button16.Visible = True
        Button17.Visible = True
        Button18.Visible = True



        If Button1.Text = table Then
            Button1.Visible = False
        End If

        If Button2.Text = table Then
            Button2.Visible = False
        End If


        If Button3.Text = table Then
            Button3.Visible = False
        End If

        If Button7.Text = table Then
            Button7.Visible = False
        End If
        If Button11.Text = table Then
            Button11.Visible = False
        End If
    Else
        lblShowMessage.Text = "Available to Reserve"
        lblShowMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green
        lblShowDate.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate
        BookingdateTextBox.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate
        btnPToPayment.Visible = True
        Button1.Visible = True
        Button2.Visible = True
        Button3.Visible = True
        Button4.Visible = True
        Button5.Visible = True
        Button6.Visible = True
        Button7.Visible = True
        Button8.Visible = True
        Button9.Visible = True
        Button11.Visible = True
        Button12.Visible = True
    End If
    db.Close()
End Sub
```

it only can disable 1 button, how can to disable more then 2 button at same time?

Comment: If something = whatever Then
            Button1.Visible = False
            Button2.Visible = False
        End If

Comment: ya.. i know but.. my problem is, i need call the data in database and check  the date and table number.
if my date is same with database, after will check the table number and see which table is booking ady..
example:
march 29 2015 this day table number 10 and table number 20 is book ady..
but.. my program just show the table number 10 is book, table number 20 still visible..
this is my problem?
i should use if statement or for , do , while, or another method??

Comment: I've added an answer to expand on it based on your new information.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you change the logic to include a while loop:

```
    dr1 = sqlcommand1.ExecuteReader

Dim count As Integer = dr1.FieldCount
        While reader.Read()
            For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1
                reserved = dr1.Item("BookingDate")
                Table = dr1.Item("NumberOfTable")

                If reservationDate < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) Then
        lblShowMessage.Text = "*You can't select previous date!"
        lblShowMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        lblShowDate.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate
        btnPToPayment.Visible = False

    ElseIf reservationDate < DateTime.Now.AddDays(7) Then
        lblShowMessage.Text = "*You have to reserve 7 days earlier!"
        lblShowMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        lblShowDate.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate
        btnPToPayment.Visible = False

    ElseIf reservationDate = reserved Then

        lblShowMessage.Text = "*This day not Available!"
        lblShowMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        lblShowDate.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate
        btnPToPayment.Visible = False

        Button1.Visible = True
        Button2.Visible = True
        Button3.Visible = True
        Button4.Visible = True
        Button5.Visible = True
        Button6.Visible = True
        Button7.Visible = True
        Button8.Visible = True
        Button9.Visible = True
        Button11.Visible = True
        Button12.Visible = True
        Button13.Visible = True
        Button14.Visible = True
        Button15.Visible = True
        Button16.Visible = True
        Button17.Visible = True
        Button18.Visible = True



        If Button1.Text = table Then
            Button1.Visible = False
        End If

        If Button2.Text = table Then
            Button2.Visible = False
        End If


        If Button3.Text = table Then
            Button3.Visible = False
        End If

        If Button7.Text = table Then
            Button7.Visible = False
        End If
        If Button11.Text = table Then
            Button11.Visible = False
        End If
    Else
        lblShowMessage.Text = "Available to Reserve"
        lblShowMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green
        lblShowDate.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate
        BookingdateTextBox.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate
        btnPToPayment.Visible = True
        Button1.Visible = True
        Button2.Visible = True
        Button3.Visible = True
        Button4.Visible = True
        Button5.Visible = True
        Button6.Visible = True
        Button7.Visible = True
        Button8.Visible = True
        Button9.Visible = True
        Button11.Visible = True
        Button12.Visible = True
    End If
            Next
         End While

dr1.Close()
```

So what this will do is for every row in the data reader it will run the check to set the reserved and table information, then allow you to run the logic against every row rather than against 1 row which is essentially what you are doing currently.

**Additional suggestions**

Give your buttons meaningful names like : ReserveTableOne, ReserveTableTwo rather than just button1 and button2 - helps when you revisit the code later on.

Change `If reservationDate < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)` to `If reservationDate <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)` otherwise it'll only do it if it's less than yesterday rather than less than or equal to yesterday - which is what you need.

Change `ElseIf reservationDate < DateTime.Now.AddDays(7)` to `ElseIf reservationDate > DateTime.Now.AddDays(7)`  which I think should be correct if you only allow people to reserve up to one week ahead, otherwise that won't allow you to reserve tables that are more than 7 days from now.

Comment: ok~~ thx your suggestions ~ =]
now i'm doing try to fix the problem..><